# Touch events on UIButton stop after delayed Animation is started

Tags: objective-c, swift, xamarin, uibutton, xamarin.ios

I am creating a `UIButton` inside a `UIView`. If I apply a transition to the `UIView` the `myButton_TouchUpInside` touch event on the `UIButton` stops firing. Can anyone advise? (*see edit*)

(**I am using Xamarin here**)

```
UIView myView = new UIView()
{
    BackgroundColor = UIColor.Black,
    RestorationIdentifier = identifier,
    UserInteractionEnabled = true,
    ClipsToBounds = true
};

UIButton myButton = new UIButton()
{
    BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red,
    UserInteractionEnabled = true
};
myButton.TouchUpInside += myButton_TouchUpInside;
myButton.SizeToFit();
myButton.Frame = new CGRect(0, 10, myButton.Bounds.Width, myButton.Bounds.Height);

myView.AddSubview(myButton);
View.AddSubview(myView);
```

Click events fire at this point. If I add a transition they stop working after the transition has occurred, I presume they have been left behind in the transition:

```
var myNewFrame = new CGRect(0, 50, myButton.Frame.Width, myButton.Frame.Height);
UIView.Transition(myView, 0.5, UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseIn, () => { myView.Frame = myNewFrame; }, null);
```

I have read that the `Frame` of the `UIButton` is the key here. I checked the `Frame` after adding it to the `UIView` and then again in the completed `Action` in the `UIView.Transition` (not shown in the code above) and it's size and position are exactly the same.

**edit**

It isn't the transition that's causing the issue, its the animation that follows (the `UIView` slides then after X seconds it fades out). Directly following the transition is this code:

```
UIView.Animate(0.25, 10, UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut, () => { myView.Alpha = 0; }, () => { myView.RemoveFromSuperview(); });
```

If I remove this, it works.

Answer (score 0):

OK, rather than using the inbuilt delay property I wrapped it in an async method as so:

```
UIView.Transition(myView, 0.5, UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseIn, () => { myView.Frame = myNewFrame; }, ()=> {FadeOut(duration)});

private async FadeOut(int duration){
    await Task.Delay(duration * 1000);
    UIView.Animate(0.25, 0, UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut, () => { myView.Alpha = 0; }, () => { myView.RemoveFromSuperview(); });
}
```